# Designing a Regex to find any Noun Phrase

Tags: python, regex, chunking

I'm trying to build a chunker (or shallow parser) using regular expressions (and without NLTK), but can't come up with a regular expression that does what I want it to do . Here's my immediate goal: find all noun phrases in a natural language text.

My first step is to tag all sentences with my home-brewed part of speech tagger, and then to join the list of token/tag pairs into a single string like so:

```
'he PRN and CC bill NP could MOD hear VB them PRN on IN the DT large JJ balcony NN near IN the DT house NN'
```

My next step is to use a regular expression to search the string for instances of noun phrases. Now the general linguistic formula for a noun phrase is: an optional determiner (DT), zero or more adjectives (JJ), and a noun (NN), proper noun (NP), or pronoun (PRN). Given this general formula, I tried this regular expression (keep in mind the tagged string alternates between words and tags):

```
'(\w+ DT)? (\w+ JJ)* (\w+ (NN|NP|PRN))'
```

Here's my code:

```
text = 'he PRN and CC bill NP could MOD hear VB them PRN on IN the DT large JJ balcony NN near IN the DT house NN'

regex = re.compile(r'(\w+ DT)? (\w+ JJ)* (\w+ (NN|NP|PRN))')
m = regex.findall(text)

if m:
     print m
```

And here's my output:

```
[('the DT', 'large JJ', 'balcony NN', 'NN')]
```

It's not finding pronouns or proper nouns, and for some reason only matching the 'NN in a '\w+ DT \w+ NN' pattern. I assumed my regex would match these patersn since I set the determiner pattern a s optional (?) and the adjective pattern as zero or more times (*).

Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
(?:(?:\w+ DT )?(?:\w+ JJ )*)?\w+ (?:N[NP]|PRN)
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/iV5qU1/2).

- `(?:(?:\w+ DT )?(?:\w+ JJ )*)?` optionally matches the DT, followed by zero or more ajectives
- '\w+ (?:N[NP]|PRN)' matched the `NN`, `NP` or `PRN`

Comment: zx81, This was helpful, but two issues. First, it needs to capture the word before the DT (adding '\w+ ' to the front of the regex does this, but I'm not sure if that's the best solution). Second (and more important), the 'word DT' must be optional. In other words, the regex you supplied does not grab the NP's, PRN's, or NN's that don't require a DT. I tried adding '(\w+ DT)?' but that didn't work.

Comment: Okay, I changed the regex and demo. Let me know if this is what you want. :)

Comment: Hey there, following up on this, did one of the answers solve it for you, or is the question still there?

Comment: It captures everything except the initial pronoun--'he PRN'. I tested it on other texts, and it works very well except for matching PRN's when they occur at the start of a sentences.

Comment: You're right. I moved the position of a space character, and I think that fixes it. Try the new demo. :)

Comment: Done. I would have voted earlier but I hadn't earned enough rep points at the time, but apparently I've since crossed that threshold :)

Comment: Thanks... See you next time. :)

Comment: zx81, Hope you're still around. I discovered an issue: the regex you supplied above works wonderfully for everything except noun phrases that just consist of an adjective and noun. For instance, in the following tagged sent:

"When SC Bill NP went VBD down IN to TO the DT big JJ store NN he PRN bought VBD ripe JJ bananas NN."

Your regex matches:

'Bill NP', 
'the DT big JJ store NN', 
'he PRN', 
'bananas NN'.

It's that last item that's the problem: it should match 'ripe JJ bananas NN.' I tried to fix it by tinkering with your regex, but no joy. Any thoughts?

Comment: See solution after quick tinker, hope it doesn't introduce new bugs. :)

Comment: That did the trick! It's matching all possible (and canonical) noun phrase patterns. Thanks again!

Comment: How to return only the words of the sentence, no tags

Answer (score 0):

Your regex would be,

```
(\w+ DT)? (\w+ JJ)*|(\w+ (?:NN|NP|PRN))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eM3dQ3)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your Demo shows it to work fairly well, but when I plug it into my program, my output is this:

[('', '', 'he PRN'), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', 'bill NP'), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', 'them PRN'), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('the DT', 'large JJ', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', 'balcony NN'), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('the DT', '', ''), ('', '', 'house NN')]

Which is not what I'm after. Not sure what's wrong(perhaps some difference in how Python processes regex's).

Answer (score 0):

> the general linguistic formula

is problematic to catch noun phrases though.

A noun phrase can contain conjunctions, *adverbs* and be *post-modified* with clauses that contain **verbs** too and what to do with gerunds?

The *really* nice man and woman *who **sold** me the book that they had for sale* = all 1 noun phrase

Charities *local, national and international* = list of adjectives

Still, it might be easier to look for groups that are NOT certain things such as verbs or prepositions FIRST.  (remember that phrases can be inside other phrases too)

^V^I